# How can I integrate selenium scripts written in python , with jmeter?

Tags: python, selenium, jmeter

I have some already working selenium scripts written in python. But, my current use case is to run them through jmeter.

I know I can add webdriver sampler in jmeter to integrate selenium with jmeter. But what if the scripts are written in python?

Is it possible or I need to convert my scripts to java?

Comment: To execute Python scripts, you should use JSR223 sampler, not the web driver. WebDriver supports only Java. But JSR223 sampler supports Python, Groovy etc.

Comment: As my current installation suggests JSR223 sampler doesn't have python as language option, though it does support groovy.

Comment: Can you try with OS Process Sampler?

Comment: Also you can use BeanShell processor to execute your python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve:

1. If you need to simply "run" tests as they are, you can:

- Download [Jython](https://www.jython.org/download) jar
- Put it under "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
- Restart JMeter
- See "jython/python" scripting option under [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

  [image: JMeter Python Selenium]

2. If you want your Selenium tests to be executed in parallel with existing JMeter test the easiest option would be using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool for executing both [JMeter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) and [Selenium](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) at the same time.
3. If you need to use your Python Selenium tests for creating the load, converting them to JMeter format will be a much better idea as using real browsers memory footprint is huge therefore you won't be able to conduct more or less immense load.

   - set Selenium to [use JMeter as a proxy](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)
   - run JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
   - run your Selenium tests
   - perform correlation and parameterization if required

     You can also check out [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter#comment-3221373832) article for an alternative approach assuming automated correlation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this covers the whole scenario, though I am only interested in use case #1.

Comment: I am able to run simple python code with your above solution (placing jython jar inside lib).  But, I can't run selenium code. That's probably because selenium isn't installed in my jython. I searched a lot, but can't figure out how to install a python module so that it works with a jython jar. Would you please add this to the answer?

Comment: Dimitri, I am encountering this issue also. In item no.1 above, the Jython link is a dead link, I am wondering if you can show what should the jython link lead to?

Answer (score 0):

(Adding as an answer as i'm 4 points from commenting)

Jython works.

I would suggest looking at [Locust.io](http://locust.io).  It's python's answer to jmeeter.  It's free.  It's python native, so one can easily port into it.